# http to https redirect using URL rewrite module in IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-8

I am trying to set up redirect from http to https for my entire site by using URL rewrite module.
IIS version 8.5 .
However, after applying several different settings in web.config I faced following:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

-- the above one makes site working but without performing redirects

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" negate="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

-- this one redirects too many times

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
                    redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security"
                    pattern=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

--results in error

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="http to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.something.net/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

--does not work neither

Any ideas?

*_____________After enabling FRT and implementing Jalpa's solution I got following - compact view (XML log is too big) -----*

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

*------------- Complete request trace - interesting parts -----*

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

[![enter image description here][6]][6]

It is worth mentioning that http and https versions of the same URLs are working fine when requested directly. If I apply redirect part in config, both versions indicate : too many redirects error.

Comment: Read FRT to learn what happens, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: In FRT I am getting this for the general_response_entity_buffer:<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://xxxxx/87887/gff.aspx">here</a></body>  and in browser the error message: Too many redirects..  in href it points to https location

Comment: @Neno did you tried below suggested rule?. could you share proper frt log here?

Comment: @Jalpa, I just added the screenshots of FRT Compact view. Your proposed config is implemented.

Comment: do you have any other rule in your site? if possible please share the request detail tab snapshot from URL rewrite start to URL rewrites end as shown in this image:[img](https://i.imgur.com/74SGhmI.png)

Comment: @Jalpa, I added what you were asking for. Looks quite different from yours.

Comment: it looks like some other rule is causing this issue. please check that is there any other rule is there in your site or at server level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the others facing the similar problem - check the load balancer rules.

Answer (score 0):

you could use below rule:

```
 <configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image]

[image]

make sure you configured https binding properly and the URL rewrite module is installed.

[image]